# Exchange open file attachtment msg

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server

Hello everyone i'm try to get te content of a mail on outlook, this mail have a `.msg` as `attachment` and i'm try to open them.

```
                if (message.HasAttachments)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var sender = message.Sender.Address;
                        var processed = ProcessAttachment(message, tmpStartFolder, tmpExtractFolder, dataCapFolder,sender);
                        emailMessage.Move(processed ? processFolder.Id : attentionFolder.Id);
                    }
                    catch (Exception r)
                    {
                        _logContext.Log(LoggerMessageType.Error, $"Function: ProcessImageList | Message: {r.Message} | Inner Message: {(r.InnerException != null ? r.InnerException.Message : "")}", DateTime.Now, Administrator, Environment.MachineName);
                    }
                }

 private bool ProcessAttachment(Item message, string tmpStartFolder, string tmpExtractFolder, string dataCapFolder, string sender)
{
    foreach (var fileAttachment in message.Attachments.Select(attachment => attachment as FileAttachment))
    {

    }
}
```

The `message` has the email and my `fileAttachment.Name` is null that means the Exchange Web Service doesn't allow .msg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias_Por_Nada.jpg

```
foreach (Attachment att in message.Attachments)
{
            //Load the attachment 
            att.Load();
            //turnt the message.Attachments to a Item(Object)
            ItemAttachment ItemAtt = att as ItemAttachment;
            //Create a ItemSchema of Attachments in itemAtt  
            ItemAtt.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments));
            foreach (Attachment scannedAttachment in ItemAtt.Item.Attachments)
            {
                scannedAttachment.Load();
                //Loads all Item Attachments as File Attachments
                FileAttachment fileAttachment = scannedAttachment as FileAttachment;
                if (Regex.IsMatch(fileAttachment.Name, ".pdf|.PDF|.Pdf"))
                {

                }
            }
}
```